# Why is IF !empty() function responding to on-page values but not from database?

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, is-empty

I would like to echo a fields value from the db if it's ISSET().  When I test the following code with set and not set values from the same page, it works fine.

```
if (!empty($row['YY'])) {
    echo $row['YY'];
} else {
    echo "N/A";}
```

This displays a "YES"

```
$row['YY'] = 'YES';
```

And this displays an "N/A"'

```
$row['YY'] = '';
```

However, when use the same code for a fetched query from the db, the set value is correctly displayed, BUT an empty field is displays nothing at all.  **How do I get an empty field to display the ELSE command of "N/A"?**

Also, the column I am fetching from, is NOT set to NULL. (In case that's relevant.) And I have tried with the following functions unsuccessfully as well;  empty(), isset(), !isset()

Comment: What does `var_dump($row['YY'])` output?

Comment: just var_dump the $row variable and see what's inside.
(Also, make sure all errors are displayed)

Comment: has it occurred to you that `$row['YY']` could be a space, or a string of non-visible chars (like a new line or something)? Because it sounds like that is the case here

Comment: Please know that I am just learning php. The  $row['YY'] = 'YES'; will not exist on the page (just used for testing). So when fetching from db, I;  echo var_dump($row['YY']); and it displayed: string 'Aspen' (length=5)

Comment: Also when the db field is empty, the var_dumb displays;  string '  ' (length=2).   So it appears that there is still a value being received from an empty field.  So where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an empty string in your `$row['YY']` it would return true on `! empty()` check.

To reproduce above problem:

```
$row  = array('YY' => ' ');

if ( ! empty($row['YY'])) {
   echo 1;
}
```

Prints 1 on screen

So add [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) function to remove white space:

```
$row['YY'] = trim($row['YY']);
```

Comment: He has empty string, not string contains a space.

Comment: if it was empty string then `! empty` check would not fail.

Comment: @GGio The trim() function is what made the difference in this case, which was pulling values from a varchar() column.  However, it was not necessary when I used the same code to retrieve empty values from char() column. Does this sound like a logical behavior?